# Displaying co-ordinates of points Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, plot

I want to display points in a 30x30 grid at random whenever my code is run, there are 10 points in total.  The 10 points  will be plotted in a area 30 by 30 defined as A1.  x going from 0 to 30 and y going from 0 to 30. I want the coordinates of these 10 points

```
 A1 = 30; % area defined as 30 X 30 grid
N = 10; % 10 tags
% Generate x and y position of tags 

for ii = 1:N
    xtemp = A1*rand(1,1);
    ytemp = A1*rand(1,1);

end

plot (xtemp,ytemp)
grid on
```

When I run the code i get more than ten points, what i want is just 10 points on the graph and the co-ordinates of each random point chosen to be displayed. The code only seems to work when the matrix is not (1,1)

Comment: Do you not want `rand(1,1);`. `rand(1,10);` will give you 10 points * N so you get 10 random values for each run in the for loop.

Comment: I used (1,10) when testing I forgot to restore it to 1x1. I want 10  random points to be plotted with their x,y co-ordinates displayed as well. The range of the points is defined by A1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the loop. It is doing the same in each iteration, and you are only using the result of the last iteration.

To plot individual points, use a mark such as `'.'` or `'o'`. This is passed as a third argument to `plot`:

```
A1 = 30;
N = 10;
xtemp = A1*rand(1,N);
ytemp = A1*rand(1,N);
plot(xtemp, ytemp, '.')
grid on
axis([0 A1 0 A1])
```

To add text labels showing each point's coordinates:

```
xoffset = 0;
yoffset = -1;
fsize = 8;
temp_str = mat2cell(num2str([xtemp(:) ytemp(:)], '(%.2f,%.2f)'), ones(1,N));
text(xtemp+xoffset, ytemp+yoffset, temp_str, 'fontsize', fsize)
```

You may want to change the format specifier `'(%.2f,%.2f)'`; `xoffset` and `yoffset` to control label position; and `fsize` to define font size. Note that it's likely that some labels partially overlap. You can reduce the chance of overlapping using smaller values of `fsize`.

Comment: Thanks you're right. The only thing left is to display the x,y co-ordinates of each point chosen. Also is it possible to fix the grid size as 30x30.

Comment: For the grid size: add `axis([0 30 0 30])` (see edited answer). As for "display the x,y co-ordinates of each point chosen", I'm not sure what you mean. That's what the line `plot(xtemp, ytemp, '.')` does, right?

Comment: Say a point is chosen that has the co-ordinates 3,25 I would like that to be shown on the graph

Comment: I know the co-ordinates can be read off the graph but it would be easier if each point had its co-ordinate displayed like a tag/label attached to it

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant. I'll play around with the labels later.

Comment: Welcome! As you may know, you can also control font size (see edited answer). That will help reducing overlap